# Actions used in form making in php

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms

I created a form in php named form.php, gave the error statements in the same file. I created another php file named test.php which connects form.php to my local database and submits the data. Now in form.php if I use

> form action="test.php" method="post" name="form1"

it directly submits data into the database without judging or showing the errors, if I use

> form action=" htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])" method="post" name="form1"

then it judge and shows the errors but does not submit the data to my database.

Please help me in this regard.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to nest PHP code blocks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14353182/how-to-nest-php-code-blocks)

Comment: "action ='test.php' " will submit your form to test.php with all your form fields.And the other one will submit to to your same script file. try to echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] and see the result

Comment: I echoed... All I understood that I've to write the database connection code inside the form.php but not getting exactly how to do that properly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you've written the errors checking and validation conditions in your 'form.php' script, and connections with your db are done through the 'test.php'.

A better way would be to keep everything on the same file. Move your connection code to form script, and that should work.

The reason is if you write form action="test.php" method="post" name="form1"
the values of the form are directly transferred to the test.php, and no code of form.php is interpreted. When you do the latter, the test.php isn't considered at all, because it doesn't get any info saying that go to that file.

Comment: Sir, I did the same as I moved my test.php code to my form.php but when I executed it's showing errors saying the variables are undefined. But I did defined the variables. I'm not getting where I'm doing wrong in merging those files.